# Asp.net server migration from 2003 to 2008 configuration file issue

Tags: migration, app-config, configuration-files, windows

I have a windows application program, exe for this application is executed remotely by some other system. 
Now there are server upgrade activity carried out and application is moved to new server 2008 from 2003

There is no change in configuration section made by me.

Here is how the config file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <section name="somesettings" type="Someapplication.Infrastructure.somesettings" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
 <somesettings setting1="Value1" setting2="value two" 
                  setting3="third value" />
</configuration>
```

Now the issue is, post migration from 2003 ( 32 bit ) to 2008 ( 64 bit ) the windows application could not read the custom configuration defined at configSections section.

Not able to find settings required post migration which will enable the program to read config sections settings.

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: If I move confisection setting to appsettings it somehow works, however its not feasible to change entire config at this moment.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/309654/

Comment: Earlier program build on ‘Any CPU’ platform which runs as a 64-bit process and some of the older components are limited to 32-bit.
Resolution : 
Compile and building the program on X86 platform which runs as 32 bit process on new servers ( 2008 R2 ) resolves the issue !